# Create a table from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to create the following table in SQL Server:

```
Id   Had_appointment      Date        Month     Year   Clinic
1          1           2019-01-03    January    2019      A
1          1           2019-01-05    January    2019      B
5          1           2019-04-03     April     2019      C
```

From the following:

```
Id    Admin_codes         Date        Clinic
1         AAA2         2019-01-03       A
1         D22S         2019-01-03       A
1         FFD3         2019-01-05       B
1         E222         2019-01-05       B
5         EEE1         2019-04-03       C
5         P332         2019-04-03       C
5         AA33         2019-04-03       C
5         XC22         2019-04-03       C
6         A000         2019-02-19       C
7         A999         2019-03-11       C
```

How can I do this? I don't want to include any individuals in my table who 1) did not have appointments & 2) have specific Admin_codes such as 'A000' and 'A999'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the SQL you wrote that is producing the incorrect output?

Comment: Have you even tried anything???

Comment: I am struggling with the first idea of creating a 1 for Had_appointment if there is an id with a date in the other table and admin_codes not equal to 'A000' or 'A999'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by selecting distinct records for the appointments (treating every admin_code other than 'A000' and 'A999' as an appointment).

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Id, '1' AS 'Had_appointment', t.[date], datename(month, [date]) [Month], year([date]) [Year], t.Clinic
FROM @t t   
WHERE Admin_codes NOT IN ('A000', 'A999')
```

Please see demo **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78bc40a2b82277bcd3cc058008b35023)**.

Answer (score 0):

By "table" I'm assuming you mean query/resultset. In addition to @sacse's Answer, you can also accomplish the same with GROUP BY.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE ( id INT, Admin_codes VARCHAR(4), [Date] DATE, Clinic VARCHAR(1) );
INSERT INTO @Data ( id, Admin_codes, [Date], Clinic ) VALUES
    ( 1, 'AAA2', '2019-01-03', 'A' ),( 1, 'D22S', '2019-01-03', 'A' ),( 1, 'FFD3', '2019-01-05', 'B' ),
    ( 1, 'E222', '2019-01-05', 'B' ),( 5, 'EEE1', '2019-04-03', 'C' ),( 5, 'P332', '2019-04-03', 'C' ),
    ( 5, 'AA33', '2019-04-03', 'C' ),( 5, 'XC22', '2019-04-03', 'C' ),( 6, 'A000', '2019-02-19', 'C' ),
    ( 7, 'A999', '2019-03-11', 'C' );

SELECT
    id,
    1  AS Had_appointment,
    [Date], 
    DATENAME ( month, [Date] ) AS [Month], 
    YEAR ( [Date] ) AS [Year], 
    Clinic
FROM @Data
WHERE
    Admin_codes NOT IN ( 'A000', 'A999' )
GROUP BY
    id, [Date], Clinic
ORDER BY
    id, [Date];
```

Returns

```
+----+-----------------+------------+---------+------+--------+
| id | Had_appointment |    Date    |  Month  | Year | Clinic |
+----+-----------------+------------+---------+------+--------+
|  1 |               1 | 2019-01-03 | January | 2019 | A      |
|  1 |               1 | 2019-01-05 | January | 2019 | B      |
|  5 |               1 | 2019-04-03 | April   | 2019 | C      |
+----+-----------------+------------+---------+------+--------+
```

Using GROUP BY will come in handy in the event you plan to do any additional aggregating (e.g., SUM, AVG, etc.).